# Organic-Groups theme selection

Tags: 7, theming, organic-groups

Does anyone know how to use the [OG-Theme](https://drupal.org/project/og_theme) module to set unique themes for groups?

I can't find a relevant user interface.

Comment: Have you had a look around your Appearance menu? It appears to just use the OG Theme stuff, so it doesn't create any UI, just adds a new field.

Comment: @Steven: There is nothing in the Appearance menu to set the themes for Organic groups. My best guess is it is probably set via fields but which widget?

Answer (score 2):

Found the readme file online which describes the steps to add theme selection per group.

It can be found @ [here](https://drupal.org/node/1327650?mode=2&sort=2).

It uses fields to make the selection as I suspected but the initial configuration is done via a different user interface.

Thanks for your input Steven.

Comment: 6 years after you made this comment I found it and it was super helpful. I couldn't remember where the options were to add that field to the content type. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

[Themekey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey) module will give you gross control over which theme your OG uses.

> From module documentation,
>
> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.